# How to avoid multiple ifelse statements when validating user input? [Web Forms]

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, server-side, code-behind

I have a very basic sign up page that has textbox fields like 'email','password','username'.
Although I have already used client-side validators (such as asp:RegularExpressionValidator) I also want to have a strong server-side validation. But so far I got this just for a single text field:

```
if(username.Contains(" ") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) 
{
    //error: invalid username
}
else if (username.length<8)
{
   //error: username cannot be shorter than 8 characters
}
else if (username.length>30)
{
   //error: username cannot be longer than 30 characters
}
else if (IsUsernameTaken(username))
{
   //error: this username has already been taken by someone else
}
else if (something)
{
    //some error
}
//etc etc
```

Is there a better (and more efficient) way to validate my controls without using the above code?

Edit: I am using Asp.net Web Forms

Comment: You don't mention which flavor of ASP.NET you are using (WebForms, traditional MVC, something more modern).  Most of them have attribute-based validation (often using attributes in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`).  Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: @Flydog57 Sorry I forgot to mention. I was using ASP.NET WebForms

Comment: WebForms has had pretty good validation since the dawn of time (about 20 years ago). If I remember correctly you can get it to inject matching client side script onto your page. Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using MVC, but yes, there is. You don't really want to validate your 'controls', you want to validate the model / viewmodel. When the user submits the form, you should be deserializing the submitted data into your own model/viewmodel class. In your declaration of the class that makes that viewmodel, you can use `DataAnnotations` to tell the framework the requirements for each field. Something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes; // this is a non-standard library

namespace MyProject.Models.ViewModels.Workorder
{
    public class CreateBillableUnbillableProjectViewModels
    {
        public class CreateBillableUnbillableProject : IValidatableObject
        {
            [Required]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Proposed Budget")]
            [AssertThat("ProposedBudget > 0", ErrorMessage = "You must enter a value greater than 0")]
            [Required]
            [UIHint("String")]
            [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = Settings.DataFormatStringCurrency)]
            public decimal ProposedBudget { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the markup in square brackets. These are `DataAnnotations`. Additionally, the model/viewmodel *as a whole* can be given rules that must be valid. For example, if `PropertyA` must be greater than `PropertyB`. This is why the class above implements `IValidatableObject`. Something like this:

```
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //TODO: any other validation before changing and saving this record?

            if (PropertyA <= PropertyB)
                yield return new ValidationResult($"PropertyA must be greater than PropertyB", new[] { "PropertyA" });

            var db = new MyProjectEntities();

            if (db.WorkOrders.Any(i => i.Title == Title))
                yield return new ValidationResult($"A WorkOrder with the same title already exists.", new[] { "Title" });
        }
```

All of the above (property-level validation and model-level validation) is triggered when you do a `if (ModelState.IsValid)` in your controller action.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using WebForms. Sorry for that